# getPost() method show blank array

Tags: magento

`$this->getRequest()->getPost();` shows blank array on `controller->saveAction()` when I press submit button on live server but it works on localhost.

Comment: Similar issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350387/this-getrequest-getpost-return-empty-array-in-magento-back-end-form-submi

Comment: I Use this but not working. for kind of your information its working on localhost but not on live server

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i m facing the same issue, Please suggest if anyone fixed it thanks